# How to model occupation in a personal ontology with Wikidata?

Tags: ontology, protege, wikidata, reasoning, object-property

I am trying to describe myself in a personal ontology and to integrate semantic triples from Wikidata with Protégé. I want to be sure to follow the best practices in personal ontologies to further apply automatic reasoning in a consistent way. For instance, how to express my present and past professions in Protégé? It seems that the range of object properties are only individuals and I am not sure to understand if the Wikidata entities are only individual or classes. With the following property 'occupation' (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P106) and the following entity 'software developer' (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q183888), I considered myself as an individual, 'occupation' as an object property and 'software developer' as a class. Does it really make sense to express it that way in the panel of myself as individual in Protégé:

```
Types : occupation some 'software developer'
```

The restriction type 'some' does not seem obvious/mandatory in Wikidata. For instance, the descriptions of occupations of Albert Einstein (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q937) do not match this schema. Do I have to consider myself as a class? I am not sure the description would be easier and so different.

Thank you very much for your help!